# Indexing in the CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file with indexing 1,2,3 if record 1 contain category XYZ 2 contain ABC and 3 contain TYU then it goes well.When subcategories are added say of XYZ then index 4 is added just below 1 and the indexing goes like 1,4,2,3 whereas I want it as 1,2,3,4.I have used following way:

```
$filepointer = fopen($category_filename_with_path, 'w') or error('ggg');
    foreach($all_category_data_new as $updated_data)
    {

     fputcsv($filepointer,$updated_data);
    }
```

Opening the file in appending mode is also not working.Sample format of CSV :

```
62,Inspirational||Inspirational,1,n,,FandE
64,Dog$house||Doghouse,1,n,,FandE
65,Doghouse||Doghouse,1,n,,FandE
66,testauthor||testauthor,1,n,,FandE
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: show your sample csv format.

Comment: the input and the output plz

Comment: Sample CSV format  :                                '62,Inspirational||Inspirational,1,n,,FandE
64,Dog$house||Doghouse,1,n,,FandE
65,Doghouse||Doghouse,1,n,,FandE
66,testauthor||testauthor,1,n,,FandE'

Comment: Problem is not in writing csv, problem is in generating `$all_category_data_new`.

Comment: @u_mulder :CSV data is generated correct.If i try to print the data generated it is generated correctly but saving in the incorrect format.Indexing is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

put 
`ksort($all_category_data_new);` before foreach would solve the problem, but if you are want to sort only keys, independent from values `array_values($all_category_data_new);` would solve the problem more efficiently.

**UPDATED :** Please add ksort as following.

```
$filepointer = fopen($category_filename_with_path, 'w') or error('ggg');
ksort($all_category_data_new);
foreach($all_category_data_new as $updated_data)
{
    fputcsv($filepointer,$updated_data);
}
```

Comment: :This is erasing the previously existed data in CSV too...Can you please tell me the exact location where to use it..I tried it just above the for-each loop

Comment: Could you var_dump($all_category_data_new) before and after sort ? and paste result to pastebin or gist ?

Comment: $all_category_data_new=ksort($all_category_data_new);
  foreach($all_category_data_new as $updated_data)
  {
   
         fputcsv($filepointer,$updated_data);
  }

Comment: no its wrong don't assign ksort result anything it works on reference only put like that ksort($all_category_data_new);

Comment: value of var_dumb is avialable before sorting not after

Comment: Not working...{79,Fr@g||Frg,1,n,,FandE
86,Fr@g||Frg>P||P>A||A>F2||F2,1,n,,FandE
82,Fr@g||Frg>Fartiyal||Fartiyal,1,n,,FandE
83,Fr@g||Frg>P||P,1,n,,FandE
85,Fr@g||Frg>P||P>A||A,1,n,,FandE}

Comment: I read your question again, you say you are opening the file in appending mode could you print all_category_data_new  before ksort and after ksort.

Comment: and check is sorting OK or not.